# How do I add a tabBar Item without having to add navigation controller?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have designed swiftui view and now I want to present that view on tap of tabbar icon.

I tried to the best of my abilities but I am not getting the required results. I am not sure how to add a new item in tabbarcontroller I already have four elements and I just want to add another one !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.